# Is it possible to calculate this series sum in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate value of this equation for any given `m` and `a` (a > 1, m > 1). Is there a formula in excel that can do that?

[image]

p.s. I've tried `SERIESSUM` but with no luck, either I'm doing something wrong or it's not suitable for case like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,B2))*B1^(B2-ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,B2))))
```

[image]

---

If you want to use SERIESSUM then you need use it in an array like this:

```
=SERIESSUM(B1,B2-1,-1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,B2)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]